# How to use arrow keys while navigating through file tree?

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse, ubuntu-11.04, nautilus

How can I use the arrow keys <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> (right and left) to fold or unfold directories (tree nodes) within e.g. Nautilus or Eclipse instead of using the space bar <kbd>Space</kbd>?

Is it possible to bind this? (Note: This is very useful if you want to fold a parent node while traversing in its child nodes.)

Comment: you could of course recode it (key bindings and which ones are locked down or not) yourself since its open source......... not something i would know how to do

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4747264/82216 for some workarounds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Why do i have to shift - right / left key to open and close folders in nautilus, eclipse, etc.?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55045/why-do-i-have-to-shift-right-left-key-to-open-and-close-folders-in-nautilus), dating from 2003 to 2009 :

> I think it boils down to this root issue in GTK: ["Please add common
>   keybindings for the TreeView"](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105895). The [reply from a developer](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105895#c4):
>
> > The arrow keys are already being used in GtkTreeView to move the focus rectangle over the horizontal axis.
>
> This issue was opened in 2003, the last substantial comments are also
>   some years old, so I doubt it will be fixed soon...
>
> Currently you can expand a folder using
>   <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd>.

A more recent [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/388314) (2009 to 2011) gives the same answer, so I doubt that your question
has another answer except to use these keys with <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Comment: Hmm.. Anyway, Shift + Key is better than space or +. Tnx.